# Implementing my own package(auto-completion) for Texmaker/any IDE written in python

Tags: auto-completion

Let's say, I have an *Auto completion* algorithm in python using machine learning (I haven't finished yet). The benefits of this comparing to the in-house auto-completion is personalization. Over a period of time, this algorithm learns all the words that I have typed and suggests me words for my own style. Instead of typing each and every word to in-house auto-completor.

So, how can I implement my own package into any IDE? Is there any ways to implement a python code as/include with .sty file? Can python be combined and worked with .sty file? I tried seeking the help of google like [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings), couldn't get a clear picture. Please comment below, if you need more information, my question is rather very brief.

Comment: sty files are independent from the auto-completion of an IDE. Providing something for any IDE won't work either because some of them have only a fixed set of completion recommendations. I would suggest to focus on LSP-compatible IDEs and write a little custom LSP on top of one of the existing.

Comment: @TeXnician Can just a package stand-alone do an auto-complete? Can a custom-built package override the existing auto-complete on an IDE? Imo, I can't train a custom LSP each time. Btw I appreciate the tip.

Comment: Since I want this not only for keywords but also for each word I type in the document.

Comment: No, as I said, packages are LaTeX level. That has nothing to do with an IDE. They work on a different code basis. And some of them aren't even extensible. You have to search for an editor that supports auto-completion based on a file or on LSP interaction. And the "custom LSP" wouldn't be that hard. You would train your suggestions and join them to the other LSP answers of an existing solution (acting as a proxy).

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks for clearing the path!